# Can you initiate a variable while declaring a loop in Python?

Tags: loops, python-3.x, while-loop, python-3.5

so I'm playing around in Python to learn what you can and cannot do. Right now I'm trying to make a one line loop like so

```
while i <= 100: print(i); i += 1
```

but as you guessed, this doesn't work because I haven't initialised `i`. I then tried

```
i = 0; while i <= 100: print(i); i += 1
```

But that also fails stating `invalid syntax "while"`.

Is there a way to initialise `i` on the same line?

Comment: No there is no way to do that with a `while` loop. We very rarely use `while` loops in Python (I pretty much only use them for infinite looping). You'll find `for` loops can be used for just about everything.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed many use it for infinite looping such as `while True` because true is always true aha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `for` loop

```
for i in range(101): print(i)
```